# Android Things RC522 (Galarzaa90 library)

Tags: android, nfc, android-things

I can't seem to get [Galarzaa's library](https://github.com/Galarzaa90/android-things-rc522) to work.

Neither his [example](https://github.com/Galarzaa90/android-things-rc522/tree/master/example) nor the code under "usage" on the front page compiles.

The following line (and every consecutive call on rc522 from the "usage" section) causes a problem:

```
 boolean result = rc522.authenticateCard(Rc522.AUTH_A, block, key);
```

Does any one know a tutorial or any helpfull link?

Also, do I have to configure the GPIO Pins of my build when I create it from the Android Things console under *Step 5 Edit hardware configurations*? If so, where do I find all the neccessary information? Or can I completly ignore that part, as long as my RC522 reader is properly connected to the RPi

Answer (score 0):

I did got it to work following the example. I don't recall anything wrong with the documentation, but I'll double check.

I think you are trying a very complicated method for deploying. You are supposed to use the console and the custom images when you are done developing and want to do distribution. While in development, you should use a default image and Deploy the apk using adb.

Comment: I use adb for deployment. Just saw that its also possible from the console. I tried his example again, it compiles and installs but it crashes. I didn't have much time to check why. So I'll look into it again.

Comment: I think that line only works for the mi fare format. You may want to write the nfc tag first to then read it.

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work? I managed to install it, and it also starts to read. The small LED on my NFC reader is blinking when I click on start. However, it doesn't display (on screen) what's on the card. I'm using mifare cards.